# Can profile-guided optimizations be used for simple function-specific optimization?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, visual-c++, optimization, profiling

I'm using VS2010 and doing some long-running simulations, trying to create highly optimized C++ programs. I've read about [Profile-Guided Optimizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k32f4k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Visual Studio and thought it's a little hard to use due to the 3-step process where you (a) build a binary, (b) run tests and collect data and then (c) rebuild the binary using PGO.

The thing is I already know where my bottlenecks are; thus if there's a way to just tell VS which functions to optimize I will spare the long build process above and will be able to use the regular one.

Does anyone aware of a way to do this? Maybe a way to tell VS which functions to optimize by manually generating the PGO file?

Thanks!

Comment: In gcc there is "#pragma hot" or "attribute hot" to mark heavy functions in source code.

Answer (score -1):

You already know where your bottlenecks are?

Really?

Let's just, for fun, imagine the possibility that there's one or more even bigger "bottlenecks" that you don't know what or where they are.

They are like that. They are sneaky. They can hide in plain sight.

*[This shows how I find them.](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1870/1262)*

You may actually get to a point where you need the compiler to optimize the code.
In my experience, that happens only after I've tuned out the stupid stuff I've put in that no compiler can straighten out.
And if you think *you* wouldn't put in stupid stuff, well, prove it.
We all can, and do.

Comment: Well, I agree with you about the how one should work. Having said that, it would be nice to be able to tell the compiler which are the most performance-demanding parts, and this is my question.